# Interview went well no call back Do I call the hiring manager?

Tags: interviewing

I just had an interview with a company I am very interested in.  The hiring manager hinted that he will make a decision first thing in the morning on Monday.  I was hoping to get a call all day and did not hear back.  Do I start to lose my hopes of getting a call?  I know people get busy and could take many days to finalize their decisions.  I also know I missed s few questions during the technical site of the interview.  I have a lot of experience and no doubt I can do the job.  I have already send the thank you letters.  Do I call them or just wait?

Comment: And don't sit around waiting, keep looking.

Answer (score 2):

It could very well be that the hiring manager has been busy, and simply hasn't had the time to call you yet, or you are somewhere on his to-do list. I would wait 2-3 days, and if you haven't heard anything by then, I would call and ask whether there'll be a follow-up interview or you didn't get the job, etc... (you know what I mean, right?).

If you have a lot of experience and the hiring manager is aware of that, he probably won't disregard you simply because you missed a few questions or got them wrong. Don't break a sweat just yet :)

Answer (score 1):

Give it a week or maybe less and follow up with an email. In the meantime, continue the job search. If you live in a high tech area, there are plenty of good choices out there.